# jQuery toggle moves the bottom element

Tags: html, jquery, css, sass, toggle

I have boxes with some content but not all text is displayed. On click I toggle all the text but the problem is I don't want the bottom element to move, instead I want the toggled div to be on top of the bottom element. Would anyone help with ideas how to do this? Thank you.

Ps. Also, for some reason the transition/animation doesn't work.

Here is a link to codepen: https://codepen.io/christmastrex/pen/gOwGvap and here is my code:

````
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__header js-toggle">
    <p class="card__title">“It’s not about weight it’s about how<br> your body changes”</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card__toggle">
    <p>Doing resistance training and cardio combined and I have not lost one single ounce on the scale….I was feeling horribly frustrated being it has been a month so I decided to do a progress sequence and wth look at me now!! It’s not about weight, it’s about how your body changes when you eat right and exercise! Yay!!”</p>
   </div>
 </div>
  
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__header js-toggle">
    <p class="card__title">“It’s not about weight it’s about how<br> your body changes”</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card__toggle">
   <p>Doing resistance training and cardio combined and I have not lost one single ounce on the scale….I was feeling horribly frustrated being it has been a month so I decided to do a progress sequence and wth look at me now!! It’s not about weight, it’s about how your body changes when you eat right and exercise! Yay!!”</p>
  </div>
</div>
------------------------------------------------------------
 .card {
      background-color: #fff;
      max-width: 490px;        
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;        
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 30px 0 rgba(74,74,74,.3);

    &__toggle {        
        overflow: hidden;
        max-height: 55px;

        p {
            font-size: 16px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }

    &__title { 
        font-weight: 900;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }   

    &__header {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;

        &::after{
            content: "\f078";
            font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";         
            font-weight: 400;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #d54f80;
            border: 2px solid #d54f80;
            color: #fff;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 2;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;         
            right: 0;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        }        

    }

    &.active {

        .card__toggle {
            max-height: 700px;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        }
        
        .card__header {            

            &::after { 
                background-color: #fff;
                color: red;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
        }
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------
   $(document).ready(function() {  
     $(".js-toggle").on("click", function () {
        $(".card__header.active").not($(this)).removeClass("active").next(".js-card-toggle").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next(".js-card-toggle").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).closest(".card").toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
                                 
});```
````

Comment: hi, perhaps use a flex gird?

Comment: @IronMan what do you mean exactly? Actually in my original page the boxes are displayed with flex rows and columns but it still happens the same thing

Comment: Accept my answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do find a solution after all.. I made changes to the css only

```
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 490px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 70px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px 0 rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.3);

  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -7px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.3); 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
  }

  &__toggle {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -12px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.3);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

    p {
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      line-height: 1.3;
    }

    &-s {
      max-height: 18px;
    }
  }

  &--s {
    max-width: 350px;
  }

  &__img {
    border: 5px solid #d54f80;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 1px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  &__title {
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  &__header {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

    &::after {
      content: "\f078";
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
      font-weight: 400;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #d54f80;
      border: 2px solid #d54f80;
      color: #fff;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 2;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
  }

  &.active {
    &.card::after {
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    }

    .card__toggle {
      max-height: 700px;
    }

    .card__header {
      &::after {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: pink;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to achieve this, copy it and see if it works.

****HTML:****

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__header js-toggle">
    <p class="card__title">
      “It’s not about weight it’s about how<br />
      your body changes”
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card__toggle">
    <p>
      Doing resistance training and cardio combined and I have not lost one
      single ounce on the scale….I was feeling horribly frustrated being it has
      been a month so I decided to do a progress sequence and wth look at me
      now!! It’s not about weight, it’s about how your body changes when you eat
      right and exercise! Yay!!”
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card__header js-toggle">
    <p class="card__title">
      “It’s not about weight it’s about how<br />
      your body changes”
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card__toggle">
    Doing resistance training and cardio combined and I have not lost one single
    ounce on the scale….I was feeling horribly frustrated being it has been a
    month so I decided to do a progress sequence and wth look at me now!! It’s
    not about weight, it’s about how your body changes when you eat right and
    exercise! Yay!!”
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**
.

```
card {
    max-height: 125px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 490px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 30px 0 rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.3);
    transition: 0.4s ease;

    &.active {
      max-height: 210px;
    }

    &__toggle {
      background-color: white;

      p {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
    }

    &__title {
      font-weight: 900;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    &__header {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;

      &::after {
        content: "\f078";
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
        font-weight: 400;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #d54f80;
        border: 2px solid #d54f80;
        color: #fff;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 2;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
    }

    &.active {
      .card__toggle {
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: white;
      }

      .card__header {
        &::after {
          background-color: #fff;
          color: red;
          transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

****jQuery:****

```
  $(".js-toggle").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).parents(".card"));
    $(this).parents(".card").toggleClass("active");
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does exactly the same as mine. Maybe I wasn't clear what I need. I want to achieve this https://prnt.sc/w9mwl8, and not this https://prnt.sc/w9mwys

Comment: oh sorry, by `bottom element` you meant the next card element, I didn't understand that well :'(..... I just saw you've achieved it